# Are there "standard" formats for storing GCM output?

Tags: aes

The `openssl enc -aes-256-gcm` command is broken, because it can't decrypt its own output, otherwise I would look to that as a format.

In order to decrypt a file, code needs to be able to separate the IV, Authentication Tag, and Additional Authenticated Data from the ciphertext.

Are there generally used command line tools that use a known format, that I can use as a model?

This is related to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53701/is-there-a-widely-used-protocol-which-builds-on-aes-gcm-and-defines-serializati), but it is specific to file storage.

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be something like this, I've created a [utility](https://github.com/sailorfred/gcmcrypt) that uses a simple binary <IV/salt><ciphertext><authentication tag> format.